# PHP Telegram best practises

Tags: php, bots, telegram, php-telegram-bot

I have written a website which links to a Telegram channel and provides "subscribers" with alerts when certain criteria are met. This is all fine. This works. I use the botfather and a bot however it's a pain to administer.

Every week the telegram channel changes, due to subscriptions only lasting a week.

So once a week:

1. a new channel is created,
2. the bot is added into the new channel as an administrator
3. the channel URL is entered into the bot code

Are there any methods I can use to automate this?

I'd preferably like a button which would create the channel, and add the bot without any user input. It would need to return the channel URL so I could update the message sending code.

I'm using this Gitlab package https://github.com/TelegramBot/Api

I'm just wondering if there are better ways of doing what I'm doing so I don't need to do the manual grunt work myself.

Thanks in advance, Chris

Comment: use [Signal](https://signal.org/) over Telegram. Telegram is [not secue](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/49782/is-telegram-secure/49802#49802).

Comment: Telegram is the clients choice @martin - I can't change that

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use an MTPROTO library to automate those steps because telegram bot api doesn't support them. Search for MTPROTO Client API Library.

You better go with [Td-Lib](https://core.telegram.org/tdlib)

1. [Create Channel](https://github.com/tdlib/td/blob/56163c2460a65afc4db2c57ece576b8c38ea194b/td/generate/scheme/telegram_api.tl#L1234)
2. [Add User to Channel](https://github.com/tdlib/td/blob/56163c2460a65afc4db2c57ece576b8c38ea194b/td/generate/scheme/telegram_api.tl#L1243)
3. [Export Channel Invite Link](https://github.com/tdlib/td/blob/56163c2460a65afc4db2c57ece576b8c38ea194b/td/generate/scheme/telegram_api.tl#L1244)

Then you can save invite link in a database where the bot can access.